# SwiftKueryPostgresql connection fails with error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

Tags: swift, postgresql, kitura

I'm pretty new to Swift, more specifically on Kitura. I'm using [SwiftKueryPostgresql](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Swift-Kuery-PostgreSQL) to handle communication with database.

I'm writting an ORM library for a specific project. I'm testing my connection like this (as I understood from documentation) :

```
import Foundation
import SwiftKuery
import SwiftKueryPostgreSQL
import XCTest
@testable import myprojet

final class project_ormTests: XCTestCase {
    var context: Context? = Context(pool: PostgreSQLConnection.createPool(host: "localhost", port: 5432, options: [.databaseName("project"), .userName("myproject"), .password("")], poolOptions: ConnectionPoolOptions(initialCapacity: 3)).getConnection())
    }

    func testConnection() {

        XCTAssertNotNil(context)
    }

    static var allTests = [
        ("testConnection", testConnection),
    ]
}
```

My class Context :

```
public class Context {
    private let pool : Connection

    public init?(pool : Connection?) {
        guard pool != nil else { return nil }
        self.pool = pool!
    }
}
```

When I run `testConnection()` on xcode, I reach SwiftKuery/ConnectionPool.swift on line 129 with this error

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

What am I doing wrong ? Is there something I missed ? I really have no idea what to do...

Here's my Package.swift if it can help

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "project",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "projet",
            targets: ["project"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Swift-Kuery-PostgreSQL.git", from: "1.2.0")
    ],
    targets:[
        .target(
            name: "project",
            dependencies: ["SwiftKueryPostgreSQL"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "projectTests",
            dependencies: ["project"]),
    ]
)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` error normally happens when force unwrapping and optional which is set to nil. I would suggest instead of doing `self.pool = pool!`, you can do

`guard self.pool = pool else {
  return nil
}`

The guard statement will unwrap the optional value for you and if it can't if will fall to the else.

A few things I noticed:
- In your `Package.swift` the `SwiftKuery` dependency is missing.
- It seems you have a typo in `testable import myprojet`

The line the error is pointing to is the `deinit` function for the `Connection`. This function gets called when the `Connection` is out of scope or not referenced by another object to clear the memory. You may be trying to access the `Connection` after it has been deleted thus getting an error throned.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did the changes you said (and seemed very justified) and now I have the following error : `value of type 'Connection? in assignment' does not conform to 'Connection'` which is pretty confusing

Comment: About SwiftKuery, as strange as it seems, I don't have to put it in my Package.swift because it's imported by SwiftKueryPostgresql, but at some point I have to import it explicitly to use `Connection` for example

Comment: So Swift-Kuery is an abstraction layer of our SQL Plugins. In this case, `Connection` protocol is declared in `Swift-Kuery` and used in `Swift-Kuery-PostgreSQL` but it does not expose it to the top level application.

Comment: The error is caused because you are trying to assign a type of `Connection?` to `Connection` - You first have to unwrap it. `guard let unwrapped = pool else {return nil}` and then assign it  `self.pool = unwrapped`

Comment: Ok thanks you helped me a lot. I'm very confused with strongly typed languages as I come from PHP. Hope I'll get better soon. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to learn how `guard let` works in swift but here is basically what you need to do:

```
public class Context {
    private let pool : Connection

    public init?(pool : Connection?) {
        guard let poolThatIsNotNil = pool else { return nil }
        self.pool = poolThatIsNotNil
    }
}
```